# Does Hibernate for SQLite support envers?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

So I want to use sql lite in my new project. Also I wish to use envers. I wonder if hibernate for sql lite supports envers. Does it?

Answer (score 1):

Envers is part of hibernate, as you may know. And there's no mention about envers (at the time of writing) on the [hibernate-sqlite project](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/) .

Comment: I know bouth that facts rs (at the time of writing). But I (currently) just cant check if envers functionality is compatible, works on\with that project. So I ask for any kinds of proof - like blog post or public memo or demo with source...